# Remove string instances from collection

Tags: clojure

I have this collection

```
("string" {:1 a} "string" {:2 b} "string")
```

I want to only return elements that are maps.

As so,

```
({:1 a} {:2 b})
```

Comment: Looking at these answers, it seems your question begs clarification.  Do you want to remove strings or return anything that isn't a map?

Comment: Question edited for clarification

Comment: "remove strings" vs "remove elements other than maps" - how is that clarified now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using filter maybe?

```
(filter map? coll)
```

Output:

```
({:1 3} {:2 4})
```

Comment: You can just use `(filter map? coll)` in this case.

Comment: @jmargolisvt that's a lot better. Very new to clojure obviously :)

Comment: d'oh! Simple answer - I'm new to clojure too :)

Answer (score 8):

If your intention is to remove strings in the list, you use `remove` and `sting?` predicate. This is pretty straightforward.

```
user=> (remove string? '("string" {:1 a} "string" {:2 b} "string"))
({:1 a} {:2 b})
```

If your intention is to remove elements other than map, then you'd better use `filter` and `map?` predicate, as in @Reut's answer.

Comment: I bumped this by +1 as it provides a solution to the problem space.